# Proving a continuous function that is increasing on all rational numbers is increasing

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I have the following function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous function, and $\forall q_{1},q_{2}\in \mathbb Q$ where $q_{1}<q_{2}$, we have $f(q_{1})<f(q_{2})$. I would like to prove that $f$ is increasing.

Currently, my approach is to assume towards contradiction that $\exists x_{1},x_{2}\in \mathbb R$ such that $x_{1}<x_{2}$ and $f(q_{1})>f(q_{2})$, then to somehow use the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ to prove that this would contradict $f(q_{1})<f(q_{2})$.

Since the function is continuous, my intuition says to utilize the definition of the limit in order to write this proof, but I can't figure out how to put this all together. Am I in the right direction, and if so how do I proceed from here?

Comment: For your $x_1<x_2$ find sequences $r_n,s_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $r_n$ decreases and tends to $x_1$, $s_n$ increases and tends to $x_2$ and $r_m<s_n$ for all $m,n$. Then $f(r_m)<f(s_n)$. Taking limits and using that $f$ is continuous, you get that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$. Is you definition of **increasing** the same as **strictly increasing**? Not everyone makes that choice. You can also get to $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ if you need to by choosing the sequences strictly monotonic and taking limit in $f(r_m)<f(r_1)<f(s_1)<f(s_n)$ instead.

Comment: There is a typo in your post after $x_1<x_2$: it should be $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$, not $f(q_1)>f(q_2).$

Comment: You are on the right track: since $x_1<x_2$ and $f(x_1)>\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}2,$ by continuity of $f$ at $x_1$ and density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R,$ there exists a rational number $q_1<\frac{x_1+x_2}2$ such that $f(q_1)>\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}2.$ Similarly, there exists a rational number $q_2>\frac{x_1+x_2}2$ such that $f(q_2)<\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}2.$ You get the desired contradiction: $q_2>q_1$ and $f(q_2)<f(q_1).$

Comment: By continuity and monotonicity on rational numbers  we have $$f(x)=\sup_{q<x,\,q\in \mathbb{Q}}f(q)$$ Therefore $f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$ for $x_1<x_2.$ Actually we have $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ as the interval $(x_1,x_2)$ contains rational numbers.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc can you elaborate on how this necessarily means that $f(x1)<f(x2)$ and not just $f(x1)≤f(x2)$ (ie how it means it's strictly increasing)?

Comment: There exist rational numbers $r,s$ such that $x_1\le r<s\le x_2.$ Hence $f(x_1)\le f(r)<f(s)\le f(x_2).$ Thus $f(x_1)<f(x_2).$