# $f$ is a continuous real function such that every 2 rational numbers $s<q$ satisfy $f(s)<f(q)$, prove $f$ is monotone increasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f$ is a continuous real function such that every 2 rational numbers $s<q$ satisfy $f(s)<f(q)$, prove $f$ is strictly increasing.
I tried assuming the contrary and using the intermediate value theorem, however, this theorem does not guarantee that the intermediate value that it gives me is attained at a rational point.

Comment: Suggestion: as this function is real-valued and continuous, use the fact that the rationals are dense.

Comment: You should add the condition $s<q$, otherwise $f(s)<f(q)<f(s)$ would contradict.

Comment: Between two distinct real numbers are two distinct rational numbers.

Comment: Not sure how this helps me.

Comment: Take two real numbers $x<y$ and approximate them respectively by rationals $s_n<q_n.$

Comment: Unanswered but commented [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613532).

Comment: Okay, I managed to conclude that $f(x) \le f(y)$,how can I conclude that there is no equality?

Comment: For instance, take the previous sequences $(s_n),(q_n)$ such that moreover $s_n\le s_1<q_1\le q_n.$

Answer (score 1):

**(Adapted) Rudin PMA Theorem $4.2:$**

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R},\ f$ maps $E$ into $\mathbb{R}$ and $p$ is a limit point of $E.\ $ Then,

$$ \lim_{x\to p} f(x) = q $$

if and only if

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n) = q $$

for every sequence $\{p_n\}$ in $E$ such that

$$ p_n \neq p,\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} p_n = p.$$

$$$$

We will make use of the above theorem in the following proof, which I begin presently.
Suppose $f$ is a continuous real function such that every two rational numbers $s<q$ satisfy $f(s)<f(q).$ Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $f$ is not strictly increasing.

Then $\ \exists\ x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}\ $ with $\ x_1 < x_2\ $ such that $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2).$

Using the Archimedean property of the real numbers, it is straightforward to show there exists $p_1\in\mathbb{Q}\ $ such that $\ x_1 < p_1 < x_2.\ $

If $\ f(p_1)\geq f(x_1),\ $ then let $\ p_1, p_2,\ \ldots,\ $ be a strictly increasing sequence of rational numbers such that $\ p_n \to x_2^-.\ $ [The existence of such a sequence is also straightforward to show]. Due to $f$ being continuous, $\ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to {x_2}^-} f(x)\ $ exists and is equal to $f(x_2).\ $ Therefore, due to Rudin's theorem $4.2,\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n) = f(x_2).\ $ But since $\ p_1, p_2,\ \ldots,\ $ is a strictly increasing sequence of rational numbers, $\{f(p_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ is a strictly increasing sequence, and so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n) > f(p_1) \geq f(x_1)\geq f(x_2).\ $ A contradiction has arisen.

On the other hand (similarly), if $\ f(p_1) < f(x_1),\ $ then let $\ q_1, q_2,\ \ldots,\ $ be a strictly decreasing sequence of rational numbers such that $\ q_n \to x_1^+.\ $ Due to $f$ being continuous, $\ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to {x_1}^+} f(x)\ $ exists and is equal to $f(x_1).\ $ Therefore, due to Rudin's theorem $4.2,\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f(q_n) = f(x_1).\ $ But since $\ p_1, p_2,\ \ldots,\ $ is a strictly decreasing sequence of rational numbers, $\{f(q_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ is a strictly decreasing sequence, and so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f(q_n) < f(q_1) < f(x_1).\ $ Again, a contradiction has arisen.

In summary, we supposed that $f$ is not strictly increasing, and considered two cases separately: $\ f(p_1) \geq f(x_1),\ $ and $\ f(p_1) < f(x_1).\ $ In either case, a contradiction arose. So we must conclude that $f$ is strictly increasing.